# How to use preg_replace_callback if i want to use same "string" twice on a callback?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I wrote a BBcode function that finds a match and does the replacement. However, if i need to use same preg_match it is not returning the match correctly.

the code is:

```html
<?php

//CODE EXAMPLE

class BBCode {

protected $bbcode = array();

 public function __construct() {
  // Replace [div class="class name(s)"]...[/div] with <div class="...">...</div>
  $this->bbcode["/\[div class=\"([^\"]+)\"\](.*?)\[\/div\]/is"] = function ($match) {
   return "<div class=\"$match[1]\">$match[2]</div>";
  }; 
 }

 public function rander($str) {
  foreach ($this->bbcode as $key => $val) {
   $str = preg_replace_callback($key, $val, $str);
  }
  return $str;
 }
}

?>
```

if i use just one tag it works fine! 
like that:

```
$str= "[div class="class1"]this is a div[/div]";
```

even if i use different tags it works great.

```
$str= "[div class="class1"][p]this is a  paragraph inside a div[/p][/div]";
```

but when I try to use :

```
$str = "[div class="class1"][div class="class2"]A div inside a div[/div][/div]";
```

it is not working and the output is:

```
<div class="class1">[div class="class2"]div inside a div</div>[/div]
```

istead of:

```
<div class="class1"><div class="class2">div inside a div</div></div>
```

How can i fix it to work correctly ?

Thanks!

[A link to the whole bbcode class code on github](https://github.com/putchi/php-bbcode)

Comment: I need it to use recursive replacing

Comment: try to take a look at preg_match instead of preg_replace

Comment: i already did... it seems like it finds the first match with the opanning tag "[div]" and than closes it with the first closing tag "[/div]" even if that closing tag not belongs to that tag. it dosn't make the difference... not sure if it is fixable at all....

Comment: it is the same to any BBcode tag... not only [div] (it was just an example...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp will match from the first `[div class="..."]` up to the first `[/div]` it finds. Therefore, the opening and closing div's do not match (as you can see in your example as well). To prevent this, use a look-around to prevent matching when there is another `[div` or `[/div`:

```
"/\[div class=\"([^\"]+)\"\]((?!\[div|\[\/div).)*\[\/div\]/is"
```

Note that this will match only once (only the inner `div`-pair), so you have to repeat the matching until nothing is found anymore.

Demo:

```
$str = "a[div class=\"b\"]c[div class=\"d\"]e[/div]f[/div]g";
$reg = "/\[div class=\"([^\"]+)\"\]((?!\[div|\[\/div).)*\[\/div\]/is";
preg_match($reg, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

will output:

```
array(3)
{
    [0]=>
    string(22) "[div class="d"]e[/div]"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "e"
}
```

---

Edit: Yes, as you commented, it replaces only the first match. The `*` is at the wrong place. Try this code:

```
$str = 'a[div class="b"]c[div class="d"]e[/div]f[/div]g';
$reg = "/^(.*)(\[div class=\"([^\"]+)\"\])((?!\[div|\[\/div).*)\[\/div\](.*)$/is";

$result = $str;
$step = 1;
echo "step 0: $result\n";
do {
    $result = preg_replace($reg, "$1<div class=\"$3\">$4</div>$5", $result, -1, $count);
    echo "step $step: $result\n";
    $step++;
} while ($count > 0);
```

This outputs:

```
step 0: a[div class="b"]c[div class="d"]e[/div]f[/div]g
step 1: a[div class="b"]c<div class="d">e[/div]f</div>g
step 2: a<div class="b">c<div class="d">e</div>f</div>g
step 3: a<div class="b">c<div class="d">e</div>f</div>g
```

Note: right now, it is matching one time too often, the loop is not optimal.

Comment: I tried that. it is not working also... it still won't find a match for the first bbcode tag. example output will be: [div class="class1"]<div class="class2">div inside a div[/div]</div>

Comment: thanks, your answer is helpful. but now i think it can't be done with only regexp. i also looked into some other bbcode libs on the web.. didn't find one that is complete... also tried JBBcode, but i couldn't customize some tags of my own... any sugestions ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have experience with BBcode _et al_ and I cannot suggest any libs. However, is it really necessary to use the class-contruction as in your Q? Right now, you add the reg-exp as array key (and therefore, you can not duplicate it). Perhaps you could use another method? A simple function?

Comment: I know its an old issue but, if someone is still looking for a solution the this: [link](https://github.com/putchi/php-bbcode) for my repo, could be the solution for you.